# jQuery incompatibility of versions using .map()

Tags: jquery

This code shoud return 1,2, but it works only with JQ version 1.7.2, the previous versions and the latest 1.10 produce errors....

Why is that?

Does it mean that if I use the .map() function, I wouln't be able to upgrade later on?

```
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="1" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="2" checked/>
<input type="checkbox" name="example[]" value="3" />

alert ($('input[name=example[]]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(','));
```

Is this a temporary bug?

Comment: Please don't type ENTIRELY IN UPPER CASE. There is literally never a time when this is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape `[` and `]` as they are reserved chars used in selectors. Appearance in id, name etc should be double back-slashed when using in the selector.

```
alert( $('input[name=example\\[\\]]:checked').map(function(){return this.value;}).get().join(','));
```

#### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/QWCBq/)

*From [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)*

> To use any of the meta-characters ( such as  !"#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[]^`{|}~ ) as a literal part of a name, it must be escaped with with two backslashes: \.